# Compute "distance matrix"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'll try to explain using a simple example what I am after.

```
aGrid = np.arange(1,9)
bGrid = np.arange(101, 109, 0.5)
A, B = np.meshgrid(aGrid, bGrid, indexing='ij')
np.random.seed(66)
valid = np.random.choice([True, False], A.shape)
```

think of `valid` as a matrix that determines whether you are "allowed to stay at grid point `(a, b)` or not. If you are not allowed to stay there, you have to move by reducing `b`: You need to move to the left (along the row).

I am trying to create this `transition` matrix now: For every single item in this `valid` matrix, it determines the "travel distance" that you need to go until you reach the next `True` item. The travel distance comes from the units between the elements. In this example, I have set the travel distance constant as `0.5` along the `b` dimension. If you are already on a `True` location, your distance is `0`.

Here is `valid` for the given seed:

```
array([[False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True,
         True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,
         True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,
         True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
        False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
         True, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
         True, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
        False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
         True, False, False, False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

#### some expected output

For the very first element, we cannot move more to the left to find a `True` value - the default should be `np.NaN`. For the next 5 elements along the first row, the distance is `0`: they are already at valid locations. `transition[0, 6] = 0.5`: It needs to move one element to the left.

So, the first two rows would be

```
array([[NaN,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0.5,  0,  0,
         0,  0, 0.5, 1,  0, 0.5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 0.5,  0, 0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0, 0.5,  0, 0.5],
```

I was trying to use combinations of `np.argmax` and `np.argmax` to find the "largest element that is `True`, but smaller than `x`, for each `x`, while iterating over each element `x` in `valid`. **This seems to be super inefficient.** What would be a better way to approaching this?

Perhaps there is a way to vectorize this? Also, I cannot rely on the equidistance of `0.5` as given in this example. The approach need to calculate the distance between the current cell and the next valid unit using `bGrid` (or `B`).

Comment: I edited my answer. If I understand what you exactly mean by "using bGrid", it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this does the trick:

```
transition = np.array(valid, dtype=float)
for i in range(valid.shape[0]):
    for j in range(valid.shape[1]):
        transition[i, j] = 0 if valid[i, j] else transition[i, j-1] + bGrid[j] - bGrid[j-1] if j > 0 else np.NAN
```